Custom DefaultErrorHandler not getting called in multiple bindings kafka
I have a spring cloud kafka binding consumer service. Where the main consumer topic and the dlq consumer are in different brokers. Thus I need to create multiple bindings.
The issue what I am facing is that when I just have a single binding, and accordingly the properties, the ListenerContainerCustomizer custom DefaultErrorHandler gets called after the stateless retries defined in the application property.
Code :
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaListenerConfig {

@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer(
    KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> secondaryKafkaTemplate) {
    log.info("inside ListenerContainerCustomizer ");
    return (container, destinationName, group) -> {
        log.info("inside destination {}", destinationName);
            log.info("inside destination name {}", destinationName);
            DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(
                secondaryKafkaTemplate,
                (cr, e) -> {
                    log.error("Error processing message in topic {} at partition {} with offset {}.",
                        cr.topic(), cr.partition(), cr.offset());
                    return new TopicPartition("myConsumer-dlq", cr.partition());
                }
            );
            DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer, new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)); // No retries
            container.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    };
  }
}

My application.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        EventConsumer-in-0:
          binder: mainKafka
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
              max-attempts: 2
              back-off-initial-interval: 100 #10sec
              back-off-max-interval: 900 #15min
              back-off-multiplier: 1.5
        EventConsumerDlq-in-0:
          binder: dlqKafka
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 0
            ack-off-initial-interval: 100
            back-off-max-interval: 900
            back-off-multiplier: 1.5

Now, below I am sharing the application-local.yml first with the single binding where its working properly and the defaulterrorhandler is getting called, meaning the log "inside destination " getting printed. But its not called in the multiple binding config case.
Also, the bean is getting properly injected as the log log.info("inside ListenerContainerCustomizer "); gets executed in both the cases.
And second I am sharing the application-local.yml with multiple binding where the log is not getting printed and the logic in the container not getting called (producing event).
Also, please note that in case of multiple binding I commented out the second binding (dlq consumer) but then also the producer logic is not called present in the defaulterrorhandler container.
Working application-local.yml
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            bindings:
                EventConsumer-in-0:
                    destination: my-change-record.v2
                    group: my-change-record.v2-local
                    consumer:
                        multiplex: true
                        autoStartup: true
                EventConsumerDlq-in-0:
                    destination: EventConsumer-dlq
                    group: dlq-group-local
                    consumer:
                        autoStartup: true
            kafka:
                binder:
                    brokers: localhost:9093
                    configuration:
                        max.poll.interval.ms: 1080000
                bindings:
                    EventConsumer-in-0:
                        consumer:
                            ack-mode: MANUAL

Not working application-local.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default-binder: mainKafka
      binders:
        mainKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9093
                      configuration:
                        max.poll.interval.ms: 1080000
        dlqKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: kafka-1.zone.org:9092,kafka-2.zone.org:9092,kafka-3.zone.org:9092
      bindings:
        EventConsumer-in-0:
          binder: mainKafka
          destination: change-record.v2
          group: change-record.v2-local
        EventConsumerDlq-in-0:
          binder: dlqKafka
          destination: EventConsumer-dlq
          group: dlq-group-local
      kafka:
        bindings:
          EventConsumer-in-0:
            binder: mainKafka
            consumer:
              multiplex: true
              autoStartup: true
              ack-mode: MANUAL
          EventConsumerDlq-in-0:
            binder: dlqKafka
            consumer:
              autoStartup: true


Instead of creating that second binding (EventonsumerDlq-in-0), why can't you provide the dlqProducerProperties along with the original binding? You can provide the second Kafka cluster's bootstrap configuration there. For example,
...
kafka:
  bindings:
    EventConsumer-in-0:
      binder: mainKafka
        consumer:
          multiplex: true
          autoStartup: true
          ack-mode: MANUAL
          dlqProducerProperties:
            configuration:
              bootstrap-server: <DLQ cluster server info>


issue is not with the producer bit. Its with the second kafka cluster consumer, where I want to consume events from the dlq topic.
So, in total two consumers are there, mainKafka binder and the dlqKafka binder

Can you create a small sample app on GH and share it here? We can triage the issue further.
